# Square not moving

Tags: python, pygame, game-development, pygame-surface

I'm trying to make a square move on the screen. I planned on doing this by adding int 50 to the x-coordinate variable of my square object:

```py
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(500)
    square = Square("crimson",x,200)
    x+=50
```

However, it only elongates the square horizontally in every iteration. Below is the full code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,col,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill(col)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x,y)

x = 200

squares = pygame.sprite.Group()
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(500)
    square = Square("crimson",x,200)
    x+=50
    screen.fill("cyan")
    squares.add(square)
    squares.update()
    squares.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I tried switching up the orders of `.fill()` and `.draw()` but the outcome is consistently the same. Should not `screen.fill("cyan")` erase everything on the screen and drawing afterwards make the illusion of a square moving?

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration, your main loop adds a sprite to your sprite group `squares` that is 50 pixels to the right of the last sprite.

Therefore, you don't have a single elongated rectangle, but rather multiple overlapping squares. Each square is 50 pixels to the right of its neighbor.

I think you meant to *move* your square instead. That means you need to:

1. Add an `update()` method to `class Square` that adds 50 pixels to the x-coordinate of a `Square` object's rectangle when called.
2. Add your square to the sprite group *once*.

Here is an example, tested with Python 3.10.5 and Pygame 2.5.2 on Windows 10:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,col,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill(col)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x,y)

    def update(self):
        # move the rectangle in place (ip) by adding
        # 50 pixels to its x-coordinate.
        self.rect.move_ip(50, 0)

x = 200

squares = pygame.sprite.Group()
run = True

# Initialize your square *once*
square = Square("crimson",x,200)

# Add your square to the list *once*.
squares.add(square)

while run:
    # Make sure we can exit the game
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.time.delay(500)
    screen.fill("cyan")    
    squares.update() # calls update() on all sprites in the group
    squares.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [pygame.Rect.move_ip](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) method is used to move an instance of `pygame.Rect`. Your code is creating a sequence of squares and not moving a single square.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, col, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(col)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)


squares = pygame.sprite.Group()
x = 0
# Create a square
square = Square("crimson", x, 200)
squares.add(square)
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(500)
    x += 50
    # Move the square
    square.rect.move_ip(x, 0)
    screen.fill("cyan")
    squares.update()
    squares.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```